# Why the templated c++ function does not compile under Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, type-traits

I am trying to implement a templated function so that the function only accepts inputs of some specific types. I tried std::enable_if and std::is_base_of to achieve the goal. The simplified code is shown below. The code compiles and runs with clang++ or g++ when c++11 is enabled. But when I compile it with Visual Studio 2013, it always says `could not deduce template argument for 'is_base_class'`. Can anyone tell me why Visual Studio 2013 does not compile and how to fix this problem?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
struct TypeWrapper {};

template <class T0, class T1>
struct CompoundType : public TypeWrapper<T0>, public TypeWrapper<T1> {};

template <class Type,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<
             TypeWrapper<Type>,
             CompoundType<
                 std::map<typename Type::key_type, typename Type::mapped_type>,
                 std::unordered_map<typename Type::key_type, typename Type::mapped_type>
             >
        >::value
        , Type
    >::type* is_base_class = nullptr
>
void TemplatedFunction(Type map) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::unordered_map<int, double> a;
    TemplatedFunction(a);
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the example code any further? Also, please indent it consistently, if you want people (including yourself) to grok its structure.

Comment: FYI - VS2015 works fine.

Comment: SFINAE support in VS 2013 is buggy. You may not have any work arounds other than moving to 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around:

```
template <typename T,
          typename K = typename T::key_type,
          typename V = typename T::mapped_type>
struct rebind_to_unordered_map
{
    using type = std::unordered_map<K, V>;
};

template <typename T,
          typename K = typename T::key_type,
          typename V = typename T::mapped_type>
struct rebind_to_map
{
    using type = std::map<K, V>;
};

template <class Type>
typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<
             TypeWrapper<Type>,
             CompoundType<
                 typename rebind_to_map<Type>::type,
                 typename rebind_to_unordered_map<Type>::type
             >
        >::value
        , void
    >::type
TemplatedFunction(const Type& ) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

or even

```
template <class Type,
          typename K = typename Type::key_type,
          typename V = typename Type::mapped_type,
          typename std::enable_if<
             std::is_base_of<
               TypeWrapper<Type>,
               CompoundType<std::map<K, V>, std::unordered_map<K, V>
             >
        >::value
        , Type
    >::type* is_base_class = nullptr
>
void TemplatedFunction(Type map) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That solves my problem, thank you. I prefer the second solution more.